# mule sequential flow to wait for another flow

Tags: mule

Main flow: or FLOW A

```
<mule>
    <flow name="GetQBClassesFlow1" doc:name="GetQBClassesFlow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="getClasses" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <flow-ref name="Authenticate-QB" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        <logger message="=========Acc Token==========#[sessionVars['accessToken']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="GetQBClassesFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="GetQBClassesFlow2" doc:name="GetQBClassesFlow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <logger message="=========Acc Token 2==========#[sessionVars['accessToken']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Authentication: or FLOW B

```
<mule ...>
    <quickbooks:config name="QBAuthenticate" consumerKey="${consumerKey}" consumerSecret="${consumerSecret}" doc:name="Quickbooks Online - Authenticate"/>
    <flow name="Authenticate-QB" doc:name="Authenticate-QB" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="8989" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <quickbooks:auth-user config-ref="Authenticate"
                    accessTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
                    authorizationUrl="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin"
                    callbackUrl="http://${hostname}:8989/getQBAccessToken"
                    requestTokenUrl="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token"
                    doc:name="Authenticate user" requestTokenId="tenantId"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="qbAccessToken" doc:name="getAccessToken" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="${hostname}" port="8989" path="getQBAccessToken" doc:name="Get Token"/>
        <logger message="=========GET QB Accounts ============" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <quickbooks:get-access-token config-ref="QBAuthenticate" doc:name="get access token"/>
        <logger message="=========realmId==============#[message.payload.realmId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="accessToken"
            value="#[message.payload.accessToken]" doc:name="Set accessToken" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="accessTokenSecret"
            value="#[message.payload.accessTokenSecret]" doc:name="Set accessTokenSecret" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="realmId"
            value="#[message.payload.realmId]" doc:name="Set realmId" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I have a FLOW called GetQBClassesFlow1(Main flow) which invokes another flow Authenticate-QB( authentication flow above), i.e.GetQBClassesFlow1 invokes Authenticate-QB, where Authenticate-QB waits for the user to enter details on login page, but before completion of Authenticate-QB flow, GetQBClassesFlow1 continues( suppose to wait to complete authenticate details page)  which causes the issue. I want GetQBClassesFlow1 should wait for flow Authenticate-QB to complete. How can I handle this?

output:

```
INFO  2014-08-20 11:18:03,830 [[qbprojects].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: =========Acc Token==========null
INFO  2014-08-20 11:18:03,831 [[qbprojects].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: =========Acc Token 2==========null
INFO  2014-08-20 11:18:12,712 [[qbprojects].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: =========GET QB Accounts ============
INFO  2014-08-20 11:18:12,944 [[qbprojects].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: =========realmId==============1345020
```

Comment: I see for flows: `Authenticate-QB`, `qbAccessToken`, `GetQBClassesFlow1` and `GetQBClassesFlow2`. Can you edit your question and use the real names instead of `A` and `B`? It's hard to understand what you're referring to.

Comment: @DavidDossot, I have given complete flow, there is no other code exists. It connects to intuit Quickbooks. Authenticate-QB is global element defined in Authenticate flow. qbAccessToken is the flow name in authenticate flow. GetQBClassesFlow1 and GetQBClassesFlow2 are flow names in main flow.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Is `FLOW A( main flow above)` the flow named `GetQBClassesFlow1` and `FLOW B( authentication flow above)` the flow named `GetQBClassesFlow2`? It looks like it because you say `flow A invokes flow B` and the only `flow-ref` is between `GetQBClassesFlow1` and `GetQBClassesFlow2`. It would be much more easier if you could use the real flow names in your question instead of `A` and `B`.

Comment: @DavidDossot, updated my questions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Authenticate-QB` flow is designed to be called over HTTP by an end-user, in order to perform the OAuth2 dance.

Thus you can not invoke it with `flow-ref`. The authentication part is done out-of-band of whatever else your flows are doing.

Comment: I have many application which does the authentication for quickbooks. I thought of doing refactoring the code for authentication and do the single code for authentication and make reusable of code instead of writing 100 times in each and every flow for authentication, write once and use in all the flows. Is there anyway to handle my scenario?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. All you need is the `Authenticate-QB` and `qbAccessToken` flows once per Mule application. This Mule application can contain many flows.

Comment: I have 10 mule xml file for different tasks and each needs authentication. for all the tasks user needs authentication, here I have to do authentication every xml file and cannot have a single common xml file for authentication and reuse it.

Comment: Are these 10 Mule XML files in one Mule application or in 10 Mule applications?

Comment: all are in one application. Problem I am facing is, as I have explained earlier not able to make a common component for authentication code.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: once a user has authenticated with the `QBAuthenticate` flow, all the other flows in any other XML files in the same Mule application that use the `quickbooks` connector message processors should be correctly authenticated. I don't see any QuickBooks processors in `GetQBClassesFlow1` nor `GetQBClassesFlow2` so how can you be sure the QuickBooks connector hasn't been correctly authenticated?

Comment: GetQBClassesFlow2 invokes a java component to get the complete accounts details from Quickbooks. Since Authenticate-QB flow is not complete, GetQBClassesFlow1 is trying to finish the flow which causes the error. In all other flows, I tried to use Authenticate-QB flow as a common component, but it did not workout due to above error.

Comment: `QBAuthenticate` needs to be called by a user as part of the OAuth login, it can't be called internally. Once the user has logged in, what happens if you call `qbAccessToken`? Do you get the access token?

Comment: mule and quickbook flow is designed like that, cannot change it. callbackUrl give the token details. QBAuthenticate global variable can be re used any where in the any flows.  for Authentication it as to call quickbooks:auth-user and quickbooks:get-access-token to get tokens.

Comment: So what's the problem, really, I don't get it?

Comment: in the output i am getting null( main question above), i want to get real values not null.

Comment: `<flow-ref name="Authenticate-QB"` is useless: `Authenticate-QB` has to be called by the user's browser as part of the OAuth authentication. Have you done this step? If yes and the user is correctly authenticated, then `<flow-ref name="GetQBClassesFlow2"` should work.